# Python function that takes a columns of birthdays and returns zodiac signs

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, append

Currently I am trying to create a python function that takes a column of birthday's and will return zodiac signs. 
My code looks like the following:

```
def program(birthday):
    zodiac = []
    for x in birthday:
        Month = pd.DatetimeIndex.month
        Day = pd.DatetimeIndex.day


        if ((Month ==12) and (Day >= 22)or (Month ==1) and (Day<= 19)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Capricorn")


        zodiac.append(x)
```

It runs but isn't returning a column like I expected. If anybody can catch the error the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you are using for? Is birthday something iteretable?

Answer (score 0):

what is datatype of birthday, and what your function returns.

Comment: The birthday datatype is datetime64[ns]